# Access every selected option value via multiple DIVs elements

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say that

- I have Multiple DIVs elements.
  I cannot tell how much DIVs I have
   
  Because they are generated by other app.
- Anyway, as it is pure HTML elements,
   
  I want to iterate through every DIVs by using Jquery
  Because I want to access every dropdownlists which is inside of each DIVs.

.

```
/// I want to iterate each and every Divs 
/// by using loop
for(int i=0; i<DIVs.Count; i++){       

/// I want to access each and every html dropdowns
/// I want to get each and every selected dropdown value
for(int j=0; j<DIVs[i].DropdownList.Count; j++){
    alert(DIVs[i].DropdownList[j].SelectedValue);
}

/// Then finally , I want to get hidden productID
alert(Divs[i].HiddenProductID);
}
```

So could anyone give me suggestion how could I change my upper algorithm to jquery code.

I also upload my html to [jsfiddle site](http://jsfiddle.net/myatthu1986/5qbEM/9/) so that everyone can see obvious.

Every suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: So you want selected values and hidden values separated or you want 'em paired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get two separated arrays of values and IDs, you can simply use this code:

```
var values = [];
$(".dynamicDropDownList").each(function (index) {
    var selectValue = this.value;
    values.push(selectValue);
    console.log(index + " - " + selectValue);
});
var productIds = [];
$("._class_hidden_Product_ID_").each(function (index) {
    var productId = this.value;
    productIds.push(productId);
    console.log("Product " + index + "'s id is " + productId);
});
```

If you need 'em paired you can use something like this:

```
var products = [];
$("._Individual_Product_").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    products.push({
        selectValue: $this.find(".dynamicDropDownList").val(),
        productId: $this.find("._class_hidden_Product_ID_").val()
    });
});
```

Also, you actually can tell how many divs are there. Any jQuery object has `length` property, that tells you the exact number of matched DOM elements. So `$("._Individual_Product_").length` will return needed number.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
$("div._Individual_Product_").each(function (index,elem) {    
    $("select",$(this)).each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion is also great @Chinmayee G

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code in jQuery

```
// 1. Iterate through every DIVs
$("div._Individual_Product_").each(function() {

    // 2. Iterate through every dropdownlists inside each DIVs
    $("select",$(this)).each(function(){

          // 3. Get each and every selected dropdown value
          alert($(this).val()); 
    });
});
```

You can also get the DIVs and dropdownlists counts like this:

```
var div = [];
var dropdownList = [];

// 1. Iterate through every DIVs
$("div._Individual_Product_").each(function() {

    div.push($(this));

    // 2. Iterate through every dropdownlists inside each DIVs
    $("select",$(this)).each(function(){

          dropdownList.push($(this).val());
    });

    // 3. Count dropdownlists inside each DIVs
    alert('DropdownList Count - ' + dropdownList.length);
    dropdownList = [];
});

alert('DIVs Count - ' + div.length);
```

Hope this helps!